# How to find common elements only between 2 arrays in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

```
     var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

1.)If elements are equals,show that common elemenst in output
2.)The output(common elements) should be array form

Comment: what do you expect? what have you tried? why angular?

Comment: Try using Underscore.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and inside filter function use  [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods to check second array includes the element.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var res = array1.filter(function(v) { // iterate over the array
  // check element present in the second array
  return array2.indexOf(v) > -1;
  // or array2.includes(v)
})

console.log(res);
```